# How to get unique value from a column in which cell has multiple values

Tags: mysql

How can I get all distinct values from a column in which cells can have multiple values?

```
   column
  val1,val2
  val1
  val1,val2,val3
```

a cell can have multiple values.
I am using MySQL

Results should by like this

```
Column
Val1
Val2
Val3
```

Comment: Please explain further what you want? Are you wanting to do more than just query for the overall column value? Also, I would really suggest avoiding having multiple comma separate values in one column. It's generally bad practice for DB design.

Comment: This is going to be really difficult. You shouldn't put lists in a column in the first place.

Comment: Like MANY of the pandas problems we see here, this would be MUCH easier to solve if you cleaned up the data before moving it into a dataframe.  This also points out why it is a bad idea to have multiple values in a column.  It violates 3rd Normal Form.

Comment: @TimRoberts actually it is violating 1st NF
And I know it is bad practice but what can I do my client was not listing and wanted it like this.

Comment: I know, that's just an item for future readers to note.  My basic point is still valid: you should tweak this data before pulling it into pandas.